# JDBC: default holdability of a ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

is there a defined default for the holdability of ResultSet, if `Connection.setHoldability()` is never invoked or a holdability is never specified during the creation of a statement?

I could not find anything in the JDBC api docs - so is it implementation specific?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "The default holdability property of a
>   ResultSet object is implementation
>   defined. The default holdability of
>   ResultSet objects returned by the
>   underlying data source can be
>   determined using the APIs provided by
>   JDBC 3.0."

Please see this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#CHDIHAFD) for reference.

Answer (score 4):

The default holdability is implementation specific, but you can get the default holdability by calling the getResultSetHoldability method on the DatabaseMetaData for the Connection.

You can also see section 6.1.9 in the Oracle / Sun JDBC docs for details: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html